# Replace dataframe missing value with the given default value by dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have datarame and I need to replace the missing value with the given default value from dictionary.
the dictionary:

```
col_to_def_val = {'director_name':'unknown',
'actor_1_name':'unknown', 'actor_2_name':'unknown', 'actor_3_name':'unknown', 'genres':'unknown',
'plot_keywords':'unknown', 'movie_title':'unknown', 'movie_imdb_link':'unknown', 'country':'unknown'}
```

key is column and value is the default value.
any suggestions?

I tried using

```
df[key]= df[key].fillna(col_to_def_val[key])
```

but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

All your columns need to be replaced with `unknown` from what I see. Therefore, you can simply pass:

```
df['key'] = df['key'].fillna("unknown")
```

There's no need to do it column-wise for this particular case, where all columns are defaulted to the same value.